# CSS for navigation

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a HTML ul li based navigation requirement. How can I get the drop down to show up similar to how it looks like when we go to www.microsoft.com. For: ex if we go to www.microsoft.com and click on products it shows the list of products in the same dropdown window and the list of Entertainment in another column. How can we create a css for this? This is what I have

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="link" target="">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="link" target="">Menu 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
           <a href="link" target="">Sub Menu 1</a>
             <ul>
               <li>
                 <a href="link" target="">sub Menu 1a </a>
               </li>

               <li>
             <a href="link" target="">sub Menu 1b </a>
               </li>

               <li>
              <a href="link" target="">sub Menu 1c </a>
               </li>
             </ul>
          </li>

        <li>
        <a href="link" target="">Sub Menu 2</a>
                 <ul>
                   <li>
                     <a href="link" target="">sub Menu 2a </a>
                   </li>

                   <li>
                 <a href="link" target="">sub Menu 2b </a>
                   </li>

                   <li>
                  <a href="link" target="">sub Menu 2c </a>
                   </li>
                 </ul>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="link" target="">Sub Menu 3</a>
                     <ul>
                       <li>
                         <a href="link" target="">sub Menu 3a </a>
                       </li>

                       <li>
                     <a href="link" target="">sub Menu 3b </a>
                       </li>

                       <li>
                      <a href="link" target="">sub Menu 3c </a>
                       </li>
                     </ul>
      </li>
     </ul>
     </li>
       <li> <a href="link" target="">Menu 2</a>   
         <ul> 
           <li> <a href="linl" > sub Menu 1 </a> </li>
           <li>  <a href="link2"> sub Menu 2 </a> </li>
         </ul> 
       </li>

     </ul>
```

So in my case when someone clicks on Menu 1 it should show Sub Menu 1 in the drop down window and show sub menu 1a,1b,1c below it and then show Sub menu 2 and show sub menu 2a,2b,2c below it ...  And if there is a long list of menu items it should show it in multiple columns.. Any one have a example css which accomplish this requirement?

Comment: Three link-only answers at this question. What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of examples available just by Googling "CSS dropdown menu".

One of the most well-known (and the one I always used) was this one: http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/